Unable to get GPU running after a recent update to Ubuntu 22.04
After a recent update to my machine, I can no longer access or use my GPU. I have fully uninstalled and then reinstalled NVIDIA drivers, CUDA, and nvidia-cuda tool kit. I have also disabled security boot. Here is some info about my machine and the what is currently installed but somehow not accessible:
> cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
...

Along with my GPU / cuda info,
> ubuntu-drivers devices
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU106M [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile / Max-Q Refresh]
driver   : nvidia-driver-545 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-550-open - third-party non-free
...

I also can still see my GPU which is weird:
> sudo lshw -C display
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU106M [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile / Max-Q Refresh]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f3000000-f3ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:2000(size=128) memory:f4080000-f40fffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080

If anyone has any idea how to address this issue I would love to hear it.

It would seem there was actually a solution to this which I found almost immediately after posting this from here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1423145

Could you please pull in the pertinent parts of that AU answer, with attribution, so that this Answer here is self-contained? Thank you!
